# Не отображается SVG background у VerticalStackLayout

Tags: c#, xaml, maui

Здравсвуйте! Хочу поставить SVG изображение в качестве фона у `VerticalStackLayout`, а он не отображается...

Код `ContentPage`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="SmartYard.Chats.ChatsPrivatePage"
             Title="Личные чаты">
    <VerticalStackLayout
        Background="ChatsPage.background">

        <VerticalStackLayout
            x:Name="layNoMessages"
            IsVisible="true"
            VerticalOptions="Center"
            HorizontalOptions="Center">
            <Image
                Margin="0,50,0,0"
                Source="dotnet_bot"/>

            <Label 
                Text="Пока нет диалогов :("
                FontSize="20"
                />

        </VerticalStackLayout>
        <ListView
            ItemsSource="{Binding messages}"
            HasUnevenRows ="True"
            x:Name="layMessages"
            IsVisible="false">

            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ViewCell>
                        <Grid
                            Padding="20,10,20,10">
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                                <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <Image
                                Grid.RowSpan="2" Margin="5,5,10,10"
                                Source="{Binding ImageResourse, TargetNullValue={StaticResource fallbackImageUrl}}"
                                Aspect="AspectFill"
                                WidthRequest="40"
                                HeightRequest="40"/>
                            <Label
                                Grid.Column="1"
                                FontSize="16"
                                Text="{Binding Name}"/>
                            <Label
                                Grid.Row="1"
                                Grid.Column="1"
                                FontSize="12"
                                Text="{Binding message}"/>
                            <Label
                                Grid.Column="3"
                                Grid.Row="0"
                                HorizontalOptions="End"
                                Text="{Binding timeAgo}"/>

                        </Grid>
                    </ViewCell>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>

        </ListView>
    </VerticalStackLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

Cам файл в проекте:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Подскажите, пожалуйста, в чем ошибся :) Спасибо!

Comment: `Images/ChatsPage/background.svg`? А SVG вообще поддерживается в MAUI?

Comment: @aepot, да, он автоматически его конвертирует в png, плюс при создании проекта все начальные картинки даются в SVG (по типу dotnet-bot)

Comment: @aepot попробовал установить этот файл как `Source` у `Image`, все отображается корректно. Дело может быть в том, что я где-то не там этот background выставляю?

Comment: Ну так положите стек в грид, рядом с ним положите Image. Будет как фон.

Comment: @aepot если я правильно понял, Вы предлагаете сделать отдельный фон для каждого `ViewCell`, дело в том, что фон этот градиентный и необходимо сделать его на весь экран

Comment: нет, я предлагаю взять панель и положить в нее 2 контрола - картинку и стек, рядом

Comment: Не знаю как там в MAUI, но раньше, например в WPF, свойство `Background` принимало по умолчанию только цвет, если во так, как вы, писать это в виде простого текста. Чтоб это свойство принимало картинку, надо прям это и задавать, по типу `<SomeControl.Background><ImageBrush ImageSource="путь"/></SomeControl.Background>`. Так что, не уверен в правильности вашего написания.